# illegal State Exception when Unload zip File from JSP and then send redirect

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Dear Servlet Developers,

I managed to download a zip-File from a JSP bei response.setHeader... So far so good. But furthermore I want to tell the JSP in a Message Field that this has worked well. So in the code I have to do a response.setAttribute command with the message field and then a sendRedirect command to show the message in the message Field on the JSP.

Then I get an illegalState Exception, because I know, that the getHeader Command with an outputstream write close and flush has done an internal sendredirect yet.

My Question is, how I achieve to downoad the zip-File and can tell that this has worked correct in the Message-Field of the JSP without getting this Exception.

Thank's

Thomas

Here is my Code:

to download the zip-file:

```
aZipFile = aHsqlDBConnectionManager.datenbankZippen(); 

                        response.setContentType("text/zip");
                        fileName = aZipFile.getName();
                        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                        try
                        {
                            outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

                            byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(aZipFile.toPath());
                            outputStream.write(fileContent);
                            outputStream.flush();
                            outputStream.close();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            System.out.println(e.toString());
                        }
```

set Attribute to the message-field:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("MeldungKundendaten", meldung);
```

do the redirect:

```
response.sendRedirect("kundendaten");
```

Now after submit the form I receive the illegalStateException, because of the setHeader Line in my Code.

@BalusC: Sorry, I don't wanted to be rude. Nevertheless it is not neccessary to post my Code, for that I am now in the office of my Company, I managed to post the Code as Code and not as images. Can you now please show me your solution?

Thank's in forward

Thomas

Comment: Show the code you use and the error you get.

Comment: @Florent: Just replace "unload" by "download" and everything will become clear.

Comment: However clear the description is currently, it would be _much_ clearer with actual code and actual error messages. Why let us guess?

Comment: @Florent: OP wants to send a download and a redirect on the same response. That's an illegal state. How's that unclear?

Comment: @BalusC: I have to say that I'm a beginner in programming Web-Apps with servlets. Can you please tell me how I get what I want? Is there an opportunity to solve my Problem? Thank's

Comment: Yes, certainly, just with a little help of JavaScript. The approach depends on whether you actually want to show the redirected page after the download is fully saved (slightly convoluted, with a cookie poller), or to show the redirected page before the "Save As" dialogue appears (much easier, doable with an oneliner). The code shown so far is irrelevant. Actually, posting code as images instead of as text is not appreciated by the community nor the searchbots. It's relatively rude as it doesn't allow answerers the opportunity to copy paste it, nor the search engines to find it.

Comment: I'm sorry that I posted my Code as images, but before I posted it, I had to send it to my private E-Mail, and sent it as an Image has therefore been much easier to me. But now to my problem: I would certainly prefer the easier way. So I would like as you suggest to show the redirected Page before the "Save as" dialogue appears. Thank's in forward. Thomas F.